# symantec antivirus on client side

Tags: anti-virus, symantec

I have a problem with symantec anti virus on client side installation.

I have XP operating system on my comp. I had a Norton anti virus with license version but last one month, it has been expired and now I want to install symantec client version on this.
I did not uninstalled or removed the Norton anti virus from my comp.

Now I installed the symantec client version on my computer from server. It shows complete progress but not shows in control panel-> add/remove program and start -> program files.

There is any possibilities to installed the symantec anti virus without uninstalling the Norton anti virus.

Answer (score 1):

You don't ever have two antiviruses on a computer at once - its just not done. you absolutely need to remove the old AV - using the [norton removal tool](http://us.norton.com/support/kb/web_view.jsp?wv_type=public_web&docurl=20080710133834EN&ln=en_US) is not a bad idea, and install the new one once it is removed.

Comment: Better yet, dump Norton completely and use ...http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security_essentials/default.aspx

Comment: lol. I'd have suggested that, if it wasn't not answering the question. In addition, my guess is its a company mandated AV

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, two AV products are not good.

Are there any events in the Windows event log that show a failed install?  Are you able to Uninstall the Norton AV application? If so, remove and try the install again.

What Symantec application are you installing Endpoint Protection or Symantec Anti Virus Corporate Edition? Exact version?

SEP has a known issue that requires a registry change but the error shows in the event log. It is related to pending file changes.

There is also a Symantec/Norton removal app that will fully remove all traces of the applications and allow a clean install.  If you provide more info, I may be able to point you there.

Answer (score 0):

Use RevoUninstaller to remove the Norton Antivirus application. It'll remove the registry keys and files and services even if the uninstaller fails.

Then use CCleaner to find and remove any registry entries or files not removed by Revo.

Then install Symantec.